# Is the function unbounded on $[a,b]$ if there is a removable discontinuity in between $a$ and $b$?

Tags: calculus, analysis

Since we know that discontinuous function eg. $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is unbounded on $[-1,1]$ because an $M\in\mathbb{R}$ satisfying $|f(x)|\leq M$ doesn't exist for $x=0$.

So, I believe the function is unbounded on $[a,b]$ if there is a hole in between a and b. Is it correct?

Comment: By a "hole" do you mean a removable discontinuity, or just any point of discontinuity?

Comment: removable discontinuity

Comment: What led you to this belief?

Comment: What is a "hole"?

Comment: Consider the function $f(x)=\begin{cases}0~~\text{if}~x\neq 0\\ 1~~\text{if}~x=0\end{cases}$.  There is a removable discontinuity there, but the function is clearly bounded.  If you are asking for one in which the removable discontinuity is an actual "hole" where you have something like $f(x)$ is undefined for $x=0$, then that isn't a function in the first place since it is not everywhere defined.

Comment: Also, please visit [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to type with $\LaTeX$ and MathJax on this website.  Even without knowing TeX, there is absolutely no reason to have linked to an image to write $|f(x)|\leq M$.  You could have written `|f(x)|<=M` and been perfectly understood, removing the need for the picture.

Comment: Is removable discontinuity a counter example of boundedness theorem?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 I think he means a non-removable discontinuity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re not entirely wrong; you just have to clean up your thinking a little bit.

The function $f(x)=1/x$ has a hole in some sense: it is not defined at 0, so the part of its graph to the right of 0 is not connected to the part of its graph to the left of 0. (Note that $f$ is not discontinuous! When you say continuous or discontinuous, you have to be talking about continuous or discontinuous *on a certain domain where the function is defined*. $f$ is continuous on every domain on which it’s defined, like, for example, $(-\infty,0) \cup (0, \infty)$.)

However, one shouldn’t characterize boundedness in terms of holes. The function $g(x)=x$ is unbounded on $(-\infty,\infty)$ and yet has a graph with no holes.

There are also plenty of discontinuous functions which have graphs with holes but which are bounded. Consider the function which takes the value 1 at 0 and the value 0 everywhere else.

Therefore, the best way to think about unboundedness is as, simply, unboundedness—the lack of a uniform bound $M$ like in your description. There is no other way of characterizing unboundedness which is completely consistent.

That is all that needs to be said, but read further if you are curious. Your intuition that there is a connection between boundedness and continuity is not all wrong. The correct way of stating it is a theorem called the Extreme Value Theorem, which states that if $h$ is a real-valued function which is defined and continuous on the closed bounded interval $[a,b]$, then $h$ is bounded on $[a,b]$. $f$ is consistent with the theorem because $f$ is indeed bounded on every closed interval on which its defined (closed intervals not containing 0); the intervals on which $f$ is unbounded are not closed, like $(0,1]$. $g$ is consistent with the theorem because although $g$ is unbounded on the closed interval $[0, \infty)$, that interval is not bounded.

Comment: Are some of bounded discontinuous functions the counterexample of boundedness theorem?

Comment: Well, they’re not technically counterexamples, since the theorem is true. But yes, discontinuous functions, since they violate the conditions of the theorem, are free to be unbounded on closed intervals. Like consider the discontinuous function which is $0$ at $0$ and $1/x$ on $(0,1]$. Then the function is unbounded on $[0,1]$, but it is also discontinuous there.